# C# convert double to float, how to remove the garbage after seventh place

Tags: c#, floating-point, double

I have in database the field called Profit. 
In my application I calculating profit:

```
myFunds.Profit = float.Parse(Math.Round(myFunds.Profit.Value * myFunds.Stake / myFunds.Stake, 3, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString());
```

Type of myFunds.Profit is int?. Math.Round return value as double and is casting to float.
In the database profit is saved as 5,40000009536743.
I know that float has less precision than double. It is possibility to cut numbers after seventh decimal place ?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You shouldn't be using binary floating point for currency, basically. Use something which preserves *decimal digits* instead of a binary representation. It's not a matter of there being "garbage after the seventh digit" - it's a matter of using the wrong representation to start with.

See my articles on [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) for more information.

It's *really* important that you understand the differences, and why it's *simply not acceptable* to use binary floating point for monetary values with precise values which cannot be represented in binary floating point. Don't try to fudge around the problems you're having with `float` and `double` - move to the appropriate data type instead. It may be more work in the short term, but it will be *vastly* preferable in the longer term.

Comment: Ok, but what with place in memory. Float is 4 byte, double is 8 byte. Using double take more place in memory

Comment: @Robert: Buying more memory is usually a better approach than losing information :)